# Performance Profiling Tips Netbeans for client applications

Tags: java, netbeans, profiling

Do you have any tips for effective profiling using Netbeans?

The profiler is quite nice and powerful.  I've used it to find problems in some of my Eclipse RCP client applications.  However, I get the feeling that I could get some more value out of it.

Normally I set it to profile either all my classes (starting with xxx.mydomain) using an inclusive filter, or I use an exclude filter to remove all org.eclipse classes.  This helps keep the overhead down.   After running the section of code I am interested, I take a snapshot.  I analyze for hotspots and then change the code, repeat the profiling, take another snapshot and compare again.

Any other suggestions or tips on how to get the most out of the profiler with client applications?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JavaOne lab exercises are available online for free, you should be able to get some good tips there.

http://developers.sun.com/learning/javaoneonline/j1labs2008.jsp?track=1&yr=2008

Answer (score 0):

Specifically this link is interesting from the Java One Lab

http://developers.sun.com/learning/javaoneonline/j1lab.jsp?lab=LAB-8430&yr=2008&track=1